# Determine if it is a function from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to solve the exercises from *Discrete mathematics* by Kenneth H. Rosen. The below is the exercise question part (b). My understanding of functions is that it maps a single element in domain to a single element in codomain. The solution says that option **b)** is a function but can't two strings have same count of $1$s? In that case won't the function map such string to same element in codomain? Why is it still a valid function?

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A function is allowed to map two different elements into one single element. A function is *not* allowed to map one single element into two different elements.

Comment: Thanks, this  was the definition given in book so i was confused "Let A and B be nonempty sets. A function f from A to B is an assignment of exactly one
element of B to each element of A.We write f (a) = b if b is the unique element of B assigned
by the function f to the element a of A. If f is a function from A to B, we write f : A → B."

Comment: Indeed. "Exactly one element of $B$ to each element of $A$". But it does not preclude the same element of $B$ to be assigned to two *different* elements of $A$.